# Background image not showing up unless it directly visited and cached by the browser

Tags: html, css, wordpress, background-image

I have a strange issue with a particular image URL.

First of all please [visit this page](http://telve.net/t/V%C4%B0DEO/yorumlar/VQ4eLv/d%C3%BCnyam%C4%B1z-ne-kadar-b%C3%BCy%C3%BCk-herkese-bilim/) with your clean cache (it's an under development Reddit clone in Turkish language, anyway...)

So, the thumbnail image didn't show up right? Nothing, just whitespace right? I mean no thumbnail image [unlike this page](http://telve.net/t/M%C3%9CZ%C4%B0K/yorumlar/VvW3vb/dijital-d%C3%BCnyan%C4%B1n-yeni-y%C4%B1ld%C4%B1z%C4%B1-sena-%C5%9Eener/) right?

This is how we are loading the thumbnail image:

```
<div class="link-thumbnail" style="background-image: url('http://www.herkesebilimteknoloji.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/dunya.png');"></div>
```

Now please [visit the image directly](http://www.herkesebilimteknoloji.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/dunya.png) with your browser and [return back](http://telve.net/t/V%C4%B0DEO/yorumlar/VQ4eLv/d%C3%BCnyam%C4%B1z-ne-kadar-b%C3%BCy%C3%BCk-herkese-bilim/) to the problematic page. This time image showed up right?

Eventually my conclusion is; background image is not showing up unless it directly visited and cached by the browser.

So what is the mechanism/reason behind this? As you can imagine by just looking to URL, image's host is a WordPress site. So what could be the trick to prevent this image to load by `background-image: url('...')` By the way it's loading the image perfectly with `<img>` tag.

I know some wallpaper web sites doing similar trick but none of them were giving away the image directly without doing a redirection trick. I believe this case is not similar.

And last but not least; how can I handle such a case when using `background-image` ?

Answer (score 0):

You are loading this image from a different URL / wordpress system. It seems like Wordpress itself prevents images within its "file system" to be loaded as background images from other URLs.

But you can just save that image, put it on your own site and load it from there.

Comment: But I don't want to save the image into my server. How WordPress recognize the request as `background-image`? I mean `<img>` working. How WordPress differenciate that? And most importantly how can I detect such situation on server/client side programmatically so I can replace the URL.

Comment: Maybe your server refuses to load background images from other domains? What's so bad about saving that image on your server?

Comment: On this kind of web sites content is basically the link. If the thumbnail image is broken, the URL is broken. If URL is broken, what's the point :) Also I'm planning to increase thumbnail image size to min 200x200. I don't have money to pay for a server stores tremendous amount of 200x200 images. `background-image` loads url on client-side not server-side. I think you are confused.